# How can I serve up a static landing page if my server is down?

Tags: dns, server, ibm-cloud

My site is built on node.js with express.js and runs on IBM Bluemix. I'm wondering how I can provide a static landing page for cases when my server goes down.

Ideally this would handle cases even when my host goes down.

Answer (score 1):

Couple options:

1) Have more than one instance of your server, so that way if one goes down, at least one other is running.

2) Use the [IBM® Active Deploy service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ActiveDeploy/index.html#overview). And [here is a guide](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/10/09/bluemix-zero-downtime-deployment/) to achieve zero downtime deployments.

3) [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/258254/how-can-i-serve-a-static-landing-page-if-my-server-is-down) answers the use of load balancing and a second DNS to re-route when a server does not respond. You can contact [Bluemix Support](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/support/index.html#getting-help) to ask more about these options.

Also - if an app crashes, Bluemix will restart it automatically. So worst case, your server should not be down for less than 60 seconds.

Comment: I have two instances of my server and they both go down when I deploy updates.

Comment: Try this service then - https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ActiveDeploy/index.html#overview

Comment: I did a demo with the Active Deploy team. Very cool stuff. Doesn't quite meet the mark for me.

Comment: Did you have a different need?

Comment: Yes, to display something other than 'this url does not exist' whenever there is downtime. One instance there is downtime is when I deploy an update, but there are several others. IBM Bluemix goes down for scheduled maintenance, as well as other times, my app goes down because I'm not perfect and my code doesn't always error out peacefully, and so forth. Having a nice static page with our branding that says, "We're down right now, but we still love you" would be awesome.